# What does it mean that “$A[b]$ is finite on $A$”?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, definition

This information will be needed in an assignment question that I am trying to solve.

> Question: Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $B$ be an $A$-algebra. What does it means when one says that for any  $b \in B$, the subalgebra $A[b]$ is finite on $A$.

I think if $B$ is finite algebra over $A$ then there exists a finite set $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ such that $A[x_1,\dotsc, x_n] = B$. But I have to prove this statement “the subalgebra $A[b]$ is finite on $A$” using some assumptions, which lead me to conclude that my definition is wrong.

Kindly let me know the original definition.

Comment: Typically, “finite algebra” means an algebra which is finitely generated as a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it probably means that the ring $A[b]$, which consists of finite polynomials of the form
$$ a_0 + a_1 b + \cdots + a_n b^n \qquad (a_j \in A), $$
is finitely generated when considered as an algebra over $A$. I say this because the question indicates that one considers $A[b]$ as **a subalgebra**.

But more generally, it is very important to always make sure that it's clear what relations are being considered as. Many statements say that two objects are isomorphic — but *as what*? Isomorphic as rings? As algebras? As $A$-modules? Similarly one can have finitely generated rings, algebras, modules. In this way, I think that the question is unclear, and it is reasonable to ask *finitely generated over $A$ as what*? This applies even to your proposed definition. When you write that $A[x_1,..., x_n] =B$, is this as $A$-modules? As algebras? Stated differently, this is asking whether $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is the $A$-module generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, or the $A$-algebra generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ — and which of these are equal to $B$. These are different things!

I note that it is not necessarily true that $A[b]$ is finitely generated over $A$ *as an $A$-module*. For a counterexample, let $B = A[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one indeterminate over $A$. Then $B$ is an $A$-algebra, but $B$ is not finitely generated as an $A$-module. A module basis for $B$ over $A$ is
$$ 1, x, x^2, x^3, \cdots $$
However $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra, and verifying this is approximately understanding the definitions of the objects involved.

This is the final reason why I suspect that the intended interpretation is as I said above: showing the algebra $A[b]$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra.

---

Finally, I'll note that there is a key relationship between being finitely generated over a base ring as a module and as an algebra: if $b \in B$ is *algebraic* over $A$, then the subalgebra $A[b]$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module (and more trivially as an $A$-algebra). Similarly if $A[b]$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then $b$ is algebraic over $A$.